# How do I test code calling static factory methods with or without Mocks?

Tags: java, testing, groovy, tdd, spock

I have a dilemma trying to solve the following test. The class is a toggle created through the Togglz library. I'm catching the feature manager method execution because I'm using a JDBCStateReporsitory to read the toggle value and if something goes wrong with the DB I have to be able to return the default value of the toggle with the `@EnabledByDefault` annotation.

```
@Slf4j
public enum PocToggle {

    @EnabledByDefault
    USE_MY_FEATURE;

    public boolean isActive() {

        FeatureManager featureManager = FeatureContext.getFeatureManager();

        try {
            return featureManager.isActive(this);
        } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
            if (log.isWarnEnabled()) {
                log.warn(String.format("Failed to retrieve feature '%s' state", this.name()));
            }

            FeatureMetaData metaData = featureManager.getMetaData(this);
            FeatureState featureState = metaData.getDefaultFeatureState();

            return featureState.isEnabled();
        }
    }

}
```

I have no clue of how to do it because an object created by an inner utility static method doesn't allow me to Stub or Mock it. I just created the true and false paths of the test, but the test trying to cover the exception path is not working throwing me a `Expected exception of type 'java.lang.IllegalStateException', but no exception was thrown` message.

```
class PocToggleSpecification extends Specification {

    @Rule
    private TogglzRule toggleRule = TogglzRule.allEnabled(PocToggle.class)

    def "Should toggle to use my feature when it is enabled"() {

        when:
        toggleRule.enable(USE_MY_FEATURE)

        then:
        USE_MY_FEATURE.isActive()
    }

    def "Should toggle to not to use my feature when it is disabled"() {

        when:
        toggleRule.disable(USE_MY_FEATURE)

        then:
        !USE_MY_FEATURE.isActive()
    }

    def "Should throw an exception when something goes wrong"() {

        given:
        toggleRule.enable(USE_MY_FEATURE)

        FeatureManager featureManager = Stub()
        featureManager.isActive() >> { throw new IllegalStateException() }

        def featureContext = Spy(FeatureContext)
        featureContext.getFeatureManager() >> featureManager

        when:
        USE_MY_FEATURE.isActive()

        then:
        thrown IllegalStateException
    }

}
```

Could you please help me to solve this kind of test?

Comment: I hope you do not mind that I edited your subject in order to better reflect what the question is about. "How I solve this kind of test" forces everyone to read your question and analyse your problem in order to understand if the question is relevant to them.

Comment: NP, I was going to do that, but I couldn't see where edit the title. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, first of all your test would not run as expected because your toggle class catches runtime exceptions and `IllegalStateException` is a runtime exception, so it will never be thrown.

Secondly, Spock cannot mock static methods for Java classes, only for Groovy classes.

So if you do not want to fiddle around with PowerMock inside of Spock - mocking static methods is always a bad smell - you still have the option of making your toggle class more testable by making the feature manager injectable via a package-scoped setter method and then use that method from the test. Try this example:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import org.togglz.core.Feature;
import org.togglz.core.annotation.EnabledByDefault;
import org.togglz.core.context.FeatureContext;
import org.togglz.core.manager.FeatureManager;
import org.togglz.core.metadata.FeatureMetaData;
import org.togglz.core.repository.FeatureState;

public enum PocToggle implements Feature {
  @EnabledByDefault
  USE_MY_FEATURE;

  private FeatureManager customFeatureManager;

  void setFeatureManager(FeatureManager featureManager) {
    this.customFeatureManager = featureManager;
  }

  public boolean isActive() {
    FeatureManager featureManager = customFeatureManager != null
      ? customFeatureManager
      : FeatureContext.getFeatureManager();

    try {
      return featureManager.isActive(this);
    } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
      System.err.println(String.format("Failed to retrieve feature '%s' state", this.name()));
      FeatureMetaData metaData = featureManager.getMetaData(this);
      FeatureState featureState = metaData.getDefaultFeatureState();
      return featureState.isEnabled();
    }
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import org.junit.Rule
import org.togglz.junit.TogglzRule
import org.togglz.testing.TestFeatureManager
import spock.lang.Specification

import static PocToggle.USE_MY_FEATURE

class PocToggleTest extends Specification {
  @Rule
  TogglzRule toggleRule = TogglzRule.allEnabled(PocToggle.class)

  def "Feature is active when enabled"() {
    when:
    toggleRule.enable(USE_MY_FEATURE)

    then:
    USE_MY_FEATURE.isActive()
  }

  def "Feature is inactive when disabled"() {
    when:
    toggleRule.disable(USE_MY_FEATURE)

    then:
    !USE_MY_FEATURE.isActive()
  }

  def "Feature defaults to active upon feature manager error"() {
    setup: "inject error-throwing feature manager into Togglz rule"
    def featureManagerSpy = Spy(TestFeatureManager, constructorArgs: [PocToggle]) {
      isActive(_) >> { throw new IllegalStateException() }
    }

    when: "feature is disabled and feature manager throws an error"
    toggleRule.disable(USE_MY_FEATURE)
    USE_MY_FEATURE.featureManager = featureManagerSpy

    then: "feature is reported to be active by default"
    USE_MY_FEATURE.isActive()

    cleanup: "reset Togglz rule feature manager"
    USE_MY_FEATURE.featureManager = null
  }
}
```

Running the last test, you will see the log message `Failed to retrieve feature 'USE_MY_FEATURE' state` as expected. My test coverage tool also shows that it works:

[image: Test coverage]

---

**Update 2018-01-17: solution variant using PowerMock (tested with 1.6.6 and 1.7.3)**

Okay, I needed PowerMock for another reason and quickly gave your code a spin.

*Disclaimer: I do prefer the first solution above, i.e. refactoring with regard to dependency injection instead of dirty tricks with PowerMock, but for what it is worth, here is how to do it.*

The Java class has the dependency injection removed again, should be identical to the OP's original code.

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow;

import org.togglz.core.Feature;
import org.togglz.core.annotation.EnabledByDefault;
import org.togglz.core.context.FeatureContext;
import org.togglz.core.manager.FeatureManager;
import org.togglz.core.metadata.FeatureMetaData;
import org.togglz.core.repository.FeatureState;

public enum PocToggle implements Feature {
  @EnabledByDefault
  USE_MY_FEATURE;

  public boolean isActive() {
    FeatureManager featureManager = FeatureContext.getFeatureManager();

    try {
      return featureManager.isActive(this);
    } catch (RuntimeException ignored) {
      System.err.println(String.format("Failed to retrieve feature '%s' state", this.name()));
      FeatureMetaData metaData = featureManager.getMetaData(this);
      FeatureState featureState = metaData.getDefaultFeatureState();
      return featureState.isEnabled();
    }
  }
}
```

See [PowerMock wiki](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/JUnit_Delegating_Runner) for an explanation. BTW, Sputnik is Spock's JUnit runner.

```
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate
import org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik
import org.togglz.core.context.FeatureContext
import org.togglz.junit.TogglzRule
import org.togglz.testing.TestFeatureManager
import spock.lang.Specification

import static PocToggle.USE_MY_FEATURE
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mockStatic
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(Sputnik.class)
@PrepareForTest([FeatureContext.class])
class PocToggleTest extends Specification {
  @Rule
  TogglzRule toggleRule = TogglzRule.allEnabled(PocToggle.class)

  // ...

  def "Feature defaults to active upon feature manager error (power-mocked)"() {
    setup: "inject error-throwing feature manager into Togglz rule"
    def featureManagerSpy = Spy(TestFeatureManager, constructorArgs: [PocToggle]) {
      isActive(_) >> { throw new IllegalStateException() }
    }
    mockStatic(FeatureContext)
    when(FeatureContext.getFeatureManager()).thenReturn(featureManagerSpy)

    when: "feature is disabled and feature manager throws an error"
    toggleRule.disable(USE_MY_FEATURE)

    then: "feature is reported to be active by default"
    USE_MY_FEATURE.isActive()
  }
}
```

---

**Update 2 (2018-01-19):** I want to mention one more issue: Maybe you noticed that I use a `Spy` instead of a `Stub` or `Mock`. This is because your code catches an exception thrown by the feature manager (FM), but then in the catch block uses the FM again. This can be dangerous because if the FM is broken due to network or database failure, it might also fail upon your next call. So while the test gives you 100% code coverage, it does not guarantee that your application behaves as expected in production or that you are testing the right thing.

Comment: **Update:** added PowerMock example

Comment: Thanks a lot @kriegaex, I will analyze your answer and then mark as solved if apply. I have a lot of work nowdays, you know ;).

Comment: We all have a lot of work, Gabriel. This is help from professionals to professionals. If you had enough time to ask a question and make others use their spare time to answer, you should show enough respect to also check the answers within reasonable time. I am sure you will, so good luck.

Comment: I didn't understand your aggressive answer because I didn't say that I'll spend half year to check your answers, but whatever.

My question to your technical answer is: always when you use a utility you will use an injection for this kind of tests or is just for this situation. I can't reach the idea to use utilities if always you will inject the response to this utility. Thank you I appreciate your time to answer.

Comment: Spinning around your answer and giving a better analysis to the `FeatureContext.getFeatureManager() ` call, I can see this class more like a Factory than just an utility so it makes sense your answer. Thank you @kriegaex this helped me a lot.

Comment: The concept Mark and I were talking about is called [Dependency Injection (DI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). It is part of a broader concept called [Inversion of Control (IoC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control). E.g., much of the original Spring Framework revolves around the idea to provide an [IoC/DI container](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework#Inversion_of_control_container_(dependency_injection)). DI helps you decouple and modularise components and make them more testable. BTW, you do not need a framework in order to implement DI. ;-)

Comment: **Update 2:** explain usage of spy instead of stub/mock and comment about using broken feature manager in exception handler block.

Comment: The spy was just a PoC. Was an attempt to see if that way the test could pass.

Comment: A misunderstanding? In my last comment I did not ask you to explain anything. The spy was my idea, after all. You used a stub, which would not have worked because the stub does not answer like the real object in subsequent calls. I was just describing the second update of my own answer because it contains additional information for you.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the reason is that since the method `FeatureContext.getFeatureManager()` is static, you just can't place a spy, if you'll put a breakpoint at the line of creation of `FeatureManager` stub inside the test and check out in debugger the address of the created object, and then place a breakpoint in a line inside the test that tries to use this feature manager, you'll see that these are two different objects, so the expectation to throw an exception is not applicable here.

In terms of a solution:
I suggest getting rid of static code as much as you can since it's not really unit testable. For example, you could create an interface like this (ok you use enum here, but it could be easily refactored to a class used from within an enum so that you could test it):

```
public interface FeatureManagerProvider {
    FeatureManager getFeatureManager();
}

public class DefaultFeatureManagerProviderImpl implements FeatureManagerProvider {
     .... // inject this in real use cases
}
```

With this abstraction, the code could be refactored like this:

```
public class Activator {
  private FeatureManagerProvider featureManagerProvider;
  public Activator(FeatureManagerProvider provider) {
      this.featureManagerProvider = provider;
  }

  public boolean isActive() {
       ...
       FeatureManager fm = featureManagerProvider.getFeatureManager();
       ...  
  }
}
```

During the test, you could supply a stub for `FeatureManagerProvider` and check all the interactions.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark Bramnik, I will analyze your answer and then mark as solved if apply. =]

Comment: My question to your answer is: is this not over-engineered just to use an utility, thank you.

Comment: I can't really answer your question because overengineering is subjective. What I can say is that in many modern languages statics as a concept is not supported or at least not encouraged to be used. I can also say that static utilities, in general, are bad for testing the code that uses them (unless you don't mind to call these utilities in the tested code. To me, the ability to easier test things is enough to not use static methods, but again its a subjective opinion

Comment: Hmmmm, good point, but if this logic (utility) always do the same thing and is used by many other components will you always instantiate this utility each time you do it instead of instantiate it once? This is my vision as a Java Developer, I don't know if in other languages this situation is handled in a better way.

Comment: Usually writing testable code implies that you use dependency injection. So usually you have a DI container (like spring, guice, etc). So it manages a non-static version of code, providing a clean lifecycle and it instantiates the code exactly once. Static utitilies do not have a lifecycle at all: when do they  instantiated first? When does static stuff "dies"? Who knows... In DI version you have an interface (optionally) and an implementation managed by DI container

Comment: IMO Mark is right, Gabriel. His answer and mine both go in the same direction. So while it is not your fault that the tool you use, _Togglz_, uses static methods, at least you can decouple your code from it by means of DI. (But this would also apply to non-static dependencies.) Even though I did also provide a PowerMock solution in my edited answer, as I said I think it is a smell rather than a nice thing.

Comment: Thank you both, I know about DI, but I didn't know that it could be important for testable classes. These explanations increased my knowledge about this matter. It could be great to give double checks to both of you. Thank you again.